# a question about mongodb projection operator $

Tags: database, mongodb, nosql

I meet a question about mongodb projection operator **$** when i read docs!

the offical example is [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#project-array-documents)

but i got the result:

```
[
    {
        "_id": 7,
        "semester": 3,
        "grades": [
            {
                "grade": 80,
                "mean": 75,
                "std": 8
            },
            {
                "grade": 85,
                "mean": 90,
                "std": 5
            },
            {
                "grade": 90,
                "mean": 85,
                "std": 3
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": 8,
        "semester": 3,
        "grades": [
            {
                "grade": 92,
                "mean": 88,
                "std": 8
            },
            {
                "grade": 78,
                "mean": 90,
                "std": 5
            },
            {
                "grade": 88,
                "mean": 85,
                "std": 3
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

**everyone know why $ doesn't work?**

- mongo server is 4.0.12
- mongo driver is 3.3.5
- [image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Scxg.png)

Comment: It worked fine for me

Comment: i add an image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Scxg.png)

Comment: @Gale try to console the data with JSON.stringify(data) function.

Comment: i have tried, the problem is that grades should have one object rather then three,

Comment: @gale it is issue with toll ..  just use plane terminal \